# Java Date and Time Formatting

Tags: java, date, time, date-format

I am trying to format time so that the user can enter a time.

```
 b1.setStartTime(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Start time for Booking: "));
```

Is there a way of doing this for the code above?

I have tried changing the startTime in booking class to a Timestamp 
and in the main tried to use this code:

```
DateFormat timeFormatter =
    DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, b1.getStartTime());
```

But i struggle to wrap my head around it. All i want to do is allow the user to input a time as the short version e.g. 7:20 AM. and then i can use this time to compare against an SQL database.

To me the DateFormat.getTimeInstance() seems like the way to go. Should startTime in booking class be of type Date if i were to use this and how would i be able to format the user input?

Answer (score 2):

```
String datetime = [code to get time string];
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
Date date = (Date) sdf.parse(datetime);
```

In future, you can refer to the java doc for SimpleDateFormat to learn how to set the format:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I think this still isn't right... you've forgetten the symbols for AM/PM

Comment: @user1291492 oh yeah... added it now.

Comment: sdf.parse returns a Date, no need to cast anything here.

Answer (score 2):

SimpleDateFormat might be convenient for you:

```
 tf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat ("h:mm a")
```

You can use it to parse a time:

```
 Date d = tf.parse (textfield.getText ());
```

and the other way round, output a date/time in this format:

```
 System.out.println ("Time: " + tf.fomat (date));
```

Comment: If you do this: Date d = tf.parse(textfield.getText()), you could get NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException. You should never do this! The input must be sanitized, or you must surround your code with try-catch blocks to handle the exceptions.

Comment: @Ozzy: Yes, Ozzy, but I guess that's not the topic at hand.

Comment: It's bad code... You can't teach someone to write code like that.

Comment: It's just a snippet, which shows how it works. Of course the user has to read up the documentation to find out the conditions how to use it. I assume exceptions are known and coding style guides and so on. This isn't a tutorial for beginners, but a hint. But feel free to downvote.

Comment: I think the OP is a beginner, thats why I'm saying, surround it with try-catch or just check the input first.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should always check the results of JOptionPane to make sure the user actually entered something and didn't click cancel.

Second, if you know how you want your user to enter the time, you need to (a) tell them how to enter it (b) use SimpleDateFormat to parse it

Answer (score 0):

The other Answers are correct but outdated.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) team also advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

## `LocalTime`

The `LocalTime` class represents a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone.

Define a formatting pattern. The pattern seen here is for twelve-hour clock, expecting an hour value of 1-12.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "h:m a" );
```

Use that formatter to parse.

```
String input = "7:20 AM";
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse( input , f );
```

Of course you should also sanitize your data inputs and add code to capture any exceptions thrown due to invalid inputs. Such code is omitted for brevity here.

## Database

To query the database, you may be able to use the `LocalTime` object directly via `setObject`/`getObject` if your JDBC driver complies with [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) or later.

If not, convert to the old java.sql types using new methods added to the old classes. In this situation, [`java.sql.Time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html).

```
java.sql.Time t = java.sql.Time.valueOf( localTime );
```

…and the other direction…

```
LocalTime localTime = t.toLocalTime();
```