# Retrieve complete date in java from DB

Tags: java, sql-server, datetime, servlets

I have a java servlet that calls a method in a java class named OAVDbUtil.java to obtain a date from a SQL database.  I can retrieve the date but not the complete value.  In the SQL Server database the field is "EventTime" and is a datetime field and an example of the date data is;

```
2015-02-16 11:48:15.730
```

In OAVDbUtil.java I have the code to retrieve the value in a results set and place it in a variable like this, where Date is of type java.sql.Date

```
Date loginDate = myRs.getDate("EventTime");
```

But it retrieves the data as "2015-02-16".  How do I retrieve the date as "2015-02-16 11:48:15.730"?

Comment: This might contain an answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338874/java-date-and-time-formatting if I convert it to a string and then simpledateformat object.  I will try it.

Comment: If you do that, you need to ensure that the database's date format never ever changes. Better to use JDBC Timestamp, as per my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's confusing, but important to note that, unlike `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date` really is *just* the date. The time-of-day is *not* included.

For what you want, you should use a `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response.  This works apart from one thing, The time stamp in the database is 2015-02-16 11:48:15.730 but the Java.sql.Timestamp removes the zero at the end making it 2015-02-16 11:48:15.73.  Can I prevent this?

Comment: It's important to note that `java.sql.Timestamp` is a subclass of `java.util.Date`. This means that you can use a `java.text.DateFormat` (or subclasses) to format it. `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"); System.out.println(sdf.format(ts));`

Comment: I have found one way of doing it to sue the SimpleDateFormatter and use a String for EventTime instead of TimeStamp.  this outputs what I want but may cause issues when using the value to interrogate the database at the next phase

Comment: Thanks again.  yes thats what I tried as in my above comment.  It works for now.

Comment: You should use the `Timestamp` object "to interrogate the database at the next phase". Conversion to `String` should only be used for display/logging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Use [getTimestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28java.lang.String%29):

`Timestamp loginDate = myRs.getTimestamp("EventTime");`

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert it to a String.